# How can I validate this XML input?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new to XML and I need help. I have this XML code for which I have to make a schema validator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <family pol="m">Peter</family>
        <age>40</age>
        <email>ppenzov@ii.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <family pol="w">Penz</family>
        <age>65</age>
    </user>
    <user>
        <family pol="w">Penzov</family>
        <age>19</age>
        <email>pppenzov@ii.com</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

The XML scheme must follow these rules:

**family, age and email** must be strictly in order

**family** - must occur once and have at most 20 symbols

**age** - must occur once and be a number between 1 and 100

**email** - must occur at most once, but may be omitted; it should be a string between 5 and 10 symbols

How can I create a very basic example?

So far I have done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="user">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="family" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:length value="20"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:intreger">
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
              <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
              <xs:enumeration value="age" maxOccurs="1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:element name="age" type="xs:intreger">
        <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string">
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="5"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="email" maxOccurs="1"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:element name="email" type="xs:string">
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, but there are a number of issues with the schema in its current form.

First, it's not XML.  In XML, attributes are specified on the start-tag, and only on the start-tag, of an element.  So wherever you have things like this, they need to change:

```
<xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
  <!-- ... -->
</xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
```

The correct form is

```xml
<xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
  <!-- ... -->
</xs:element>
```

If this is a copy/paste error, you just need to be more careful.  If it's a conceptual issue, you need to read up on the basics of XML.  The rules of [well-formedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) are simple, but XML processors do not tolerate violations.  (They are in fact forbidden by the spec to tolerate violations.)

You will find it helpful to work with an XML-aware editor, which will alert you automatically to well-formedness issues like this.  (If you're already using one, you should work to become more attentive to its signals of distress.)

Second, after cleaning up the well-formedness issues, your schema document is not valid against the [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) schema for schema documents.  There are several problems.

- The way to bind an element to a particular type is to use *either* the `type` attribute (to bind the element to a named type) *or* a type declaration as a child (to declare an anonymous local type and bind the element to that anonymous type).  Don't use both: you're simultaneously telling the schema validator that you want to bind the element `age` (for example) to the type *xs:integer* and that you want to bind it to a different type, derived from *xs:integer* by restriction.
- The way to declare a type is to use the *xs:complexType* or the *xs:simpleType* element, not *xs:restriction*.  The structure you want is something like this:

  ```xml
  <xs:element name="age">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <!-- ... -->
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  ```

  It's not unusual find it hard to remember what goes where in an XSD schema document; many people find it pays off to work with an XSD-aware editor.
- The *xs:enumeration* element does not have an attribute named maxOccurs, and at a guess it doesn't mean what you think it means.  You seem to be speculating that *xs:enumerate* is used to specify how many times an element can occur in a given content model; that's done by the *minOccurs* and *maxOccurs* attributes on the *xs:element* element.

  The *xs:enumerate* element is used to enumerate the possible values in the value space of a type; `<xs:enumeration value="family"/>` means for example that one of the legal values of the type being defined is the string "family".  If it's the only *xs:enumeration* element in the type declaration, it means that "family" is the *only* valid value of the type.

  The *maxOccurs* attribute belongs on the *xs:element* element; in this case, since "1" is the default value of *maxOccurs*, it can be omitted on all three *xs:element* elements.  You can and should drop all the *xs:enumeration* elements in your schema document.

Once you have those errors cleared up, your schema document is legal.  But it doesn't yet mean what you want it to mean.  Again, there are several problems:

- You define the simple type for the family element by saying (among other things):

  ```xml
  <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]"/>
  ```

  This means that the value of family must consist of exactly three letters in the Latin alphabet, without diacritics.  If you want the values "Peter", "Penz", and "Penzov" to be legal, this won't do; you need to read up a bit on regular expressions and what they mean to understand how to write them more reliably.

  Many names contain characters with diacritics (consider the Polish logician Jan Łukasiewicz, the inventor of Polish notation); many contain non-alphabetic characters (blank, hyphen, apostrophe).  So restricting your 'family' element to the letters from A to Z is poor data modeling, even if you only want to deal with names in the Latin alphabet.
- You are using the *xs:length* element to try to define the maximum length of your family element; you want *xs:maxLength*, not *xs:length*, for that.

Comment: There is also the (true) typo *"intreger"* (an extra "r" (close to "t")). In `<xs:element name="age" type="xs:intreger">`. Would it be caught by some automatic means, not just inspection? Perhaps address it in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of schema generators on-line. I use them to get me started with a new XML document, creating a basic schema that focuses on the position of elements. This saves me a lot of time. Once it's working I start adding the individual field restrictions.

One final tip. Use an editor that enables you to format your XML. Schemas are difficult to read at the best of times :-(

## Schema Generators

Here's your example generated by [Freeformatter.com](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="users">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="family">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="pol" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="age"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="email" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And another generated by [xmlgrid](http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html)

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
         <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Sat Jun 22 2013 09:54:23 GMT+0100 (IST) -->
         <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
         <xs:element name="users">
               <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="user" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="family" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="pol" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```