# Why am I getting an error "the parameter is incorrect" when I try and validate my xml?

Tags: xml, vba, domdocument

I am trying to validate my xml against a schema but when I run the code, I am getting an error.  The xml (sample.xml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Catalog xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
  <Rec>
    <ITEMS dt:dt="string"/>
    <QTY dt:dt="string">1</QTY>
    <CATALOG dt:dt="string">1492</CATALOG>
    <MFG dt:dt="string">BA</MFG>
    <ASSYCODE dt:dt="string"/>
    <DESC dt:dt="string">MCB 1 POLE 2A TYPE C</DESC>
    <QUERY2 dt:dt="string">1MCB</QUERY2>
    <QUERY3 dt:dt="string">2A</QUERY3>
    <MISC1 dt:dt="string"/>
    <MISC2 dt:dt="string"/>
    <USER1 dt:dt="string">EAMCB122</USER1>
    <USER2 dt:dt="string"/>
    <USER3 dt:dt="string"/>
    <TABNAM dt:dt="string">CB</TABNAM>
    <TAGS dt:dt="string">Q2-4D</TAGS>
    <DESC1 dt:dt="string"/>
    <DESC2 dt:dt="string"/>
    <DESC3 dt:dt="string"/>
    <INST dt:dt="string"/>
    <LOC dt:dt="string"/>
    <UM dt:dt="string"/>
    <HDL dt:dt="string">h=6706</HDL>
    <DWGIX dt:dt="string">7</DWGIX>
    <REF dt:dt="string">-4D</REF>
    <SH dt:dt="string">2</SH>
    <SOURCE dt:dt="string">ELECTRICAL</SOURCE>
  </Rec>
</Catalog>
```

and the schema (sample.xsd) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
         <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Thu Nov 30 2017 16:39:38 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) -->
         <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
         <xs:element name="Catalog">
               <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="Rec" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="ITEMS">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="QTY" type="xs:int">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="CATALOG" type="xs:int">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="MFG" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="ASSYCODE">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="DESC" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="QUERY2" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="QUERY3" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="MISC1">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="MISC2">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="USER1" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="USER2">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="USER3">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="TABNAM" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="TAGS" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="DESC1">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="DESC2">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="DESC3">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="INST">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="LOC">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="UM">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="HDL" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="DWGIX" type="xs:int">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="REF" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="SH" type="xs:int">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                             <xs:element name="SOURCE" type="xs:string">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
                     <xs:attribute name="xmlns:dt" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
               </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

I generated the schema online using the xml file so am reasonably confident there shouldn't be any errors there.
The vba code I am using is:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xLists As IXMLDOMElement


    Const dir = "C:\"
    Dim xSchema As New MSXML2.XMLSchemaCache60
    Dim xSchemaErr As IXMLDOMParseError

    Call xSchema.Add("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes", LoadXML(dir & "sample.xsd"))

    Set xDoc = LoadXML(dir & "sample.xml")
    Set xDoc.Schemas = xSchema

    Set xSchemaErr = xDoc.Validate

    Set xDoc = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function LoadXML(strFilename As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim bLoadSucceeded As Boolean
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    With xDoc
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = False
        .resolveExternals = False
    End With

    If (fso.FileExists(strFilename)) Then
        bLoadSucceeded = xDoc.Load(strFilename)
        If (bLoadSucceeded) Then
            Set LoadXML = xDoc
        Else
            Call MsgBox("Load XML document failed", vbCritical, "Warning")
            Set xDoc = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Unable to find specified XML file to load", vbCritical, "Warning")
        Set xDoc = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set xDoc = Nothing

End Function
```

The problem occurs here

```vb
Call xSchema.Add("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes", LoadXML(dir & "sample.xsd"))
```

with the error `The parameter is incorrect` but I cannot see which parameter is causing the problem.  Looking at the documentation for the add method of `XMLSchemaCache60`, I cannot see any mention of this error.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thanks

Edit:
Well, after mulling this over for the last few days, I am still not sure I entirely understand  comments from `Michael Kay` other than the comment which suggested the xsd was pretty much useless so, as I am just about as useless as xmlgrid.net, I tried another; this time https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xsd-from-xml and this is what I got:

```vb
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Catalog" type="CatalogType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="ITEMSType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QTYType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CATALOGType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:short">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MFGType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="ASSYCODEType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DESCType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QUERY2Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="QUERY3Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MISC1Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MISC2Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="USER1Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="USER2Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="USER3Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TABNAMType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TAGSType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DESC1Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DESC2Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DESC3Type">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="INSTType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="LOCType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="UMType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="HDLType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="DWGIXType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="REFType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:float">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SHType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:byte">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="SOURCEType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute xmlns:urn="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" ref="urn:dt"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="RecType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="ITEMSType" name="ITEMS"/>
      <xs:element type="QTYType" name="QTY"/>
      <xs:element type="CATALOGType" name="CATALOG"/>
      <xs:element type="MFGType" name="MFG"/>
      <xs:element type="ASSYCODEType" name="ASSYCODE"/>
      <xs:element type="DESCType" name="DESC"/>
      <xs:element type="QUERY2Type" name="QUERY2"/>
      <xs:element type="QUERY3Type" name="QUERY3"/>
      <xs:element type="MISC1Type" name="MISC1"/>
      <xs:element type="MISC2Type" name="MISC2"/>
      <xs:element type="USER1Type" name="USER1"/>
      <xs:element type="USER2Type" name="USER2"/>
      <xs:element type="USER3Type" name="USER3"/>
      <xs:element type="TABNAMType" name="TABNAM"/>
      <xs:element type="TAGSType" name="TAGS"/>
      <xs:element type="DESC1Type" name="DESC1"/>
      <xs:element type="DESC2Type" name="DESC2"/>
      <xs:element type="DESC3Type" name="DESC3"/>
      <xs:element type="INSTType" name="INST"/>
      <xs:element type="LOCType" name="LOC"/>
      <xs:element type="UMType" name="UM"/>
      <xs:element type="HDLType" name="HDL"/>
      <xs:element type="DWGIXType" name="DWGIX"/>
      <xs:element type="REFType" name="REF"/>
      <xs:element type="SHType" name="SH"/>
      <xs:element type="SOURCEType" name="SOURCE"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CatalogType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="RecType" name="Rec"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

It looks as if it has addressed the import schema issue????? however I now get a new error:

```vb
sample.xsd#/schema/complexType[17][@name = 'DESC2Type']/simpleContent[1]/extension[1]/attribute[1]
Undeclared XSD attribute : '{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes}dt'.
```

I cannot understand why this is an Undeclared attribute - to me this looks just like the rest in the same document albeit with a different name!!

Comment: When I try to run the code, I get an error saying that there was an "Error parsing 'dt:dt' as NCName datatype." (But, because I know next to nothing about xml, I'm not sure how that relates to your issue.)

Comment: I highly advise renaming `LoadXML()` as that is a method in MSXML.

Comment: And `Dir` is a VBA function.

Answer (score 0):

The schema is indeed invalid (which means the online tool you chose is buggy - in fact, it's crap).

Firstly,

```
<xs:attribute name="dt:dt" type="xs:string">
```

is quite incorrect: the `name` attribute must be a simple NCName (no-colon-name). Where the attribute is in a different namespace from the containing element, the schema needs to contain an xs:import of a separate schema document for that namespace; the attribute needs to be declared in the imported schema document, and referenced in the primary schema document using the `ref` attribute:

```
<xs:attribute ref="dt:dt"/>
```

Secondly, an element declaration can't have both a `type` attribute and a `complexType` child element. The correct way to describe an element that has an attribute and also has text content is using a "complex type with simple content" as described here:

[XML Schema: Element with attributes containing only text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376582/xml-schema-element-with-attributes-containing-only-text)

I have to say the error message you are getting is pretty lousy too. Saxon gives you a list of messages of the form:

```
Error at xs:attribute on line 13 column 81 of test.xsd:
  No namespace prefix is allowed in this name {dt:dt}
```

followed by a list of messages of the form:

```
Error at xs:element on line 16 column 66 of test.xsd:
  A <complexType> element must not appear as a child of an <xs:element> with a @type attribute
```

Comment: After writing this I noticed that the schema was attributed to xmlgrid.net. Other schemas generated by xmlgrid, e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247978/how-to-validate-this-xml-input/17249033#17249033 seem to have the same problems. Since there's no way on the xmlgrid site of submitting bug reports, it's perhaps not surprising if bugs don't get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Had you properly error handled your methods to catch runtime exceptions especially working with APIs like MSXML, you would receive a more pertinent error message showing issues with schema.

```vb
Sub test()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ...


ExitHandle:
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub

' CHANGED FCT NAME TO AVOID NAME CLASH WITH MSXML's LOADXML()    
Private Function ProcXML(strFilename As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ...

ExitHandle:
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Exit Function

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ExitHandle
End Function
```

Dialog Message *(where I named the schema file CatalogExcel.xsd)*

[image: Error Message]